# How to store and access precomputed array data in Haskell?

Tags: arrays, haskell

I'm working on a Haskell library. I need to have large (~100K items) unboxed arrays with integer values to access them time to time from various library parts. The arrays are supposed to contain precomputed data that needs to be initialized once. There is no problem with the implementation of their initialization. The question is how to better structure their initialization and provide access to them for the rest of the library. I consider the following possibilities:

1. Define a record type with the arrays, and use the Reader monad to provide an environment with the precomputed data.
2. Use ST monad to build arrays, and use a regular function per array to access them.

First option seems to work, but it would require to execute all in a Reader (or in a stack of monads, where one of them is Reader). The second option seems OK, but I'm not sure that the computation results will be stored by the runtime all the time, i.e. the arrays will not be swept by GC and re-initialized again (arrays are large and their initialization is heavy). Are my reasonings correct? If so, which option is better? I admit that I might miss other possibilities, are there other ways or patterns to handle precomputed data?

Comment: I don't think the GHC runtime ever recomputes a value (except perhaps when two parallel threads enter the same thunk at the same time). If you use a global array variable you should be OK, I guess (?). Maybe I'd mark that as `NOINLINE` just to be safe. I don't add an answer since I think this should be answered by GHC runtime experts instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define an unboxed `Array` or `Vector` at top-level:

```
myData :: VU.Vector Int
myData = ...any definition...
```

then as soon as `myData` is forced to WHNF, all values will be fully computed, and all accesses to elements of `myData` will use the precomputed values.

If you don't force it manually, then all values will be precomputed the first time an element of `myData` is accessed anywhere in the program.  This may be enough.  Otherwise, you can force it in the IO monad with [`evaluate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:evaluate). The following test program illustrates the approach.  You should observe a delay between `Loading myData...` and `DONE`, but no further delays as the precomputed elements are accessed.

```
import Control.Exception
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU

myData :: VU.Vector Int
myData = VU.generate 1000000000 (*2)

main = do
  putStrLn "Loading myData..."
  evaluate myData
  putStrLn "DONE"
  print $ myData VU.! 10
  print $ myData VU.! 999999999
```

If you need to use the `ST` monad in your initialization, that's fine too.  Just do all the `ST` work in `myData` and return the final immutable vector.  For example, replacing `myData` in the above program with the following works fine:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as VUM
import Control.Monad.ST

myData :: VU.Vector Int
myData = runST $ do
  v <- VUM.generate 1000000000 id
  VUM.mapM_ (\x -> pure (x*2)) v
  VU.freeze v
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation!

Comment: BTW, isn't ``case myData `seq` () of () -> return ()`` equivalent to ``myData `seq` return ()`` ? Further, I think `evaluate myData >> return ()` should be roughly equivalent (even if I never understood the difference wrt `seq`).

Comment: @chi I've optimistically made that suggested change. Perhaps K knows some subtleties that make it a bad suggestion and will revert it, but from looking at the documentation of `evaluate` I think it's fiddly enough that reusing something already available in a library is a good idea. (e.g. it seems there's some exception-handling nonsense going on, and perhaps some weird `IO`-unboxing performance hacks that I don't understand.)

Comment: Yeah, I think `evaluate` is correct here.

Comment: @chi ``myData `seq` return ()`` is undefined (as an `IO`-program) if `myData` is undefined. `evaluate myData` is always defined (as an `IO`-program) but that program may throw an exception. There is a difference between a nonexistent imperative program (`undefined :: IO a`) and one that exists but always throws (`evaluate undefined :: IO a`).